# How do Russians call a book of wishes?

Tags: перевод

I'm looking for a russian word for the englisch term **wish book** or **book of wishes** (list of wishes exists on paper, like a book of wishes).

I stumbled upon **сонник** but this means dream book or book of dreams so it's not the right one.

Would it be just **книга жела́ние**? I'm also not sure if I can mix feminime words with neuter words.

Many thanks!

Comment: What's a "wish book" in English? Is it just a book with some wishes written in it? If so it would be *книга желаний* in Russian.

Comment: Maybe, книга жалоб и предложений?

Comment: there's no such thing in Russia, no concept => no word for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't call it **книга**. I don't even know if there is such thing in Russian.
**Книга жела́ние** is grammatically incorrect, it should be **книга жела́ний**.
What exactly do you mean by **wish book**?
Is it a printed list of wishes a person has to pick from or is it a complete list of wishes a person has at all? Or maybe it is just a catalog of goods?

The thing you are asking about is called **список желаний**.
The sample sentence would be "У меня есть список желаний, в который я записываю то, что очень хочу получить, и вычёркиваю сбывшиеся желания."

Comment: Yes, it is a book where one can write his own wishes into it. For example: "I want to start learning chinese in 2016." You keep this book and add wish after wish and someday you cross/strike some wishes because they have already been fulfilled. If you write down your wishes your subconscious mind will work towards them. But don't mix it up with a dream book. ;-)

Comment: edited the answer

Comment: Thanks! I compared Google and it's 6 million against 800 thousands (книга / список) Because I'm looking for a book I take the former one.

Comment: I think this concept just filtered into Russian language from English, and people who did that just made a literal translation. I was quite surprised when I googled книга жела́ний. I did not even know such thing existed in Russia.

Comment: I'd rater use 'книжка' or 'тетрадь'. 'Книга' typically means a ready typographic product, not intended for manual writing. 'Книжка' may be used for a small 'книга', but it can also denote a semi-fabricated product partly intended for filling ('записная книжка', 'книжка-раскраска', 'сберегательная книжка' etc). 'Тетрадь' is a copy-book, usually devoid of any print except lining or checkering.

Comment: Thats really PromtTranslation of western concept, cause there is no such thing in Russian (both language and culture of recent days). The only thing i can think of close enough to this is Santa's wishlist (https://lmgtfy.com/?q=%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B0+%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83+%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%83) but I suppose topic starter meant something personal, that you do as "personal diary".